# ruby local thread variable access from other methods

Tags: ruby, multithreading

```
class Tour
  def destinations
    threads = []
    [:new_york, :london, :syndey].each { |city|
      @threads << Thread.new {
        where = city
        goto(where)
      }
    }
    threads.each(&:join)
  end

  def where=(location)
    Thread.current[:city] = location
  end

  def where
    Thread.current[:city]
  end

  def goto(city)
    puts "I am going to visit #{city}."
  end
end

Tour.new.destinations
```

In order to access thread local variable in method goto(), the thread local variable has to be passed to it like `goto(where)`, if there are many other similar methods need to do things based upon current thread local variable :city, then it has to be passed to other methods too.

I guess there is an elegant/ruby way to avoid passing thread local variable as an option, what does that look like?

Comment: Treat it less like an imperative language and more like an object oriented language. Objects are the way to go here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like you'll trip yourself up a lot. It might be better to initialize a new object for each thread.

```
class Tour
  def self.destinations
    threads = []

    [:new_york, :london, :sydney].each do |city|
      threads << Thread.new { Destination.new(city).go }
    end

    threads.each(&:join)
  end
end

class Destination
  attr_reader :location

  def initialize(location)
    @location = location
  end

  def go
    puts "I am going to visit #{location}."
  end
end

# Tour.destinations
```

Suggested reading: https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/a-modern-guide-to-threads